# c# create an arbitrary length generic parameter string e.g. ?,?,?

Tags: c#, string

I know I am forgetting to remember how to do this and it is late.

I want to, in an elegant manner, build a placeholder list for a munged sql command.

Have a command with an arbitrary number of parameters, need to build `?,?,?`

Did I mention that it was a *wet* brain fart? this is what came out:

You are welcome to make me feel like more of an idiot if you just remember me what I am forgetting. ;-)

---

Ok, looks like I should be calling it a night.

Both you guys confirmed what I was doing before going off the deep end.

This is my name list,

```
string names = string.Join(",", _command.Parameters.Cast<SQLiteParameter>().Select(p => p.ParameterName).ToArray());
```

And I just replaced the p.Name with '?'

```
string vals = string.Join(",", _command.Parameters.Cast<object>().Select(p => "?").ToArray());
```

But for some reason I did not approve.

Thanks.

Comment: If it's for an SQL Command why not use parametrized query parameters? String manipulation in SQL queries might lead to bad results.

Comment: @Darin: This *is* a parameterized query. The point is that the number of query parameters isn't known at compile time.

Comment: @jon limjap, leave it alone, please. I just banged that into the question box. As soon as I looked at it I realized how stupid it was.

Comment: @Darin, it is for a SQLite command. And Skeet is right, 'arbitrary' being the key word ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Along the lines of @Jon's answer:

```
string.Join(",", _command.Parameters.Cast<object>().Select(p => "?").ToArray())
```

Comment: That is EXACTLY what I have in my code that prompted this question. Lol. too funny. Maybe that is the best way after all. I just thought it smelled.

Comment: string.Join(",", _command.Parameters.Cast<object>().Select(p => "?").ToArray());

Answer (score 2):

Well, this suggests itself:

```
string x = string.Join(",", Enumerable.Repeat("?", count).ToArray());
```

In .NET 4 this can be simplified slightly as `string.Join` has new overloads:

```
string x = string.Join(",", Enumerable.Repeat("?", count));
```

On the other hand, I'd be tempted to just do it with a loop:

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    builder.Append("?,");
}
builder.Length--; // Remove trailing ,
return builder.ToString();
```

Either way I'd put it in a separate method, so the brevity isn't likely to matter.

Comment: Yeah, the first one I look similar to what I have, then I started shaving my llama and tried to convince myself that a regex would be good. Am on the tail end of a binge and am coming up short. just want to get throught this section before calling it a night without leaving something stupid in the file.  Thanks.

Comment: r.e. separate method: this is going to be only ever called one time, ever, to build a 'bulk copy' command in a simple implementation, so will probably be inline, thus the silly imperative for elegance.

Comment: @Sky: Even if it's only going to be used once, you may well still be able to improve the readability by separating it out into a new method. If it's a choice between a more easily-understood separate method or a relatively dense single statement, I'd go for the separate method.